# How to make transition go back and forth once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I've heard of animations/transitions that occur multiple times. I need a transition that changes the width once and then changes it back (again, over a three-second interval) after a two-second pause. How would I do this?

Here's my code:

```
<html> 

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Page 2</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    /* Your styles go here */
    img {
        width:200px; 
        height:100px; 
        animation-name: widthChange; 
        animation-duration: 3s;
        -webkit-animation-name: widthChange; 
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
        -moz-animation-name: widthChange; 
        -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
        -0-animation-name: widthChange; 
        -0-animation-duration: 3s;   


    }

    p {text-align:center}
    button {margin:20px}
    .stylized {
        font-style: italic;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: yellow;
        border-style: outset;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes widthChange {
        from {width: 200px;}
        to {width: 400px;}
        from {width: 400px;}
        to {width: 200px;}
    }
    @-o-keyframes widthChange {
        from {width: 200px;}
        to {width: 400px;}
        from {width: 400px;}
        to {width: 200px;}
    }
    @-moz-keyframes widthChange {
        from {width: 200px;}
        to {width: 400px;}
        from {width: 400px;}
        to {width: 200px;}
    }
    @keyframes widthChange {
        from {width: 200px;}
        to {width: 400px;}
        from {width: 400px;}
        to {width: 200px;}

    }

    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       // jQuery methods go here...
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').addClass("loaded");
        $('img').addClass("loaded2");
        $("#button1").click(function() {
            $("button").addClass("stylized");
            $("#button1").html("Fancy Button 1");
            $("#button2").html("Fancy Button 2");
            $("#button3").html("Fancy Button 3");
        });
       });

    });
    /* Your additional JavaScript goes here */
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img class = "image" src="elephant.jpg" alt="elephant"/>
    <p><button id="button1">Button 1</button><button id="button2">Button 2</button><button id="button3">Button 3</button></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
        width:200px; 
        height:100px; 
        animation: widthChange 3s 2s;
        -webkit-animation: widthChange 3s 2s;
        -moz-animation: widthChange 3s 2s;
        -0-animation: widthChange 3s 2s;


    }

    p {text-align:center}
    button {margin:20px}
    .stylized {
        font-style: italic;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: yellow;
        border-style: outset;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes widthChange {
        0%, 100% {width: 200px;}
        50% {width: 400px;}
    }
    @-o-keyframes widthChange {
        0%, 100% {width: 200px;}
        50% {width: 400px;}        }
    @-moz-keyframes widthChange {
        0%, 100% {width: 200px;}
        50% {width: 400px;}
    }
    @keyframes widthChange {
        0%, 100% {width: 200px;}
        50% {width: 400px;}

    }
```

```html
<img class = "image" src="elephant.jpg" alt="elephant"/>
    <p><button id="button1">Button 1</button><button id="button2">Button 2</button><button id="button3">Button 3</button></p>
```

Use `%` and `animation-delay`

Comment: Think there's some confusion, needed the pause not at the beginning but rather after after the stretch and before the un-stretch.

Comment: @FrankTocci Ah, okay, give me a minute and I'll update